# Table in Markdown doesn't show

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

I want to do a simple latex table in my markdown raport:

```
---
title: "Title"
output: html_document
---

## Table

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
\hline
 & chisq & df & p \\ 
\hline
mu & 0.889 & 1 & 0.346 \\ 
sigma & 0.810 & 1 & 0.368 \\ 
Q & 0.663 & 1 & 0.415 \\ 
P & 0.663 & 1 & 0.415 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

but my table does not show up. There is no error so i don't know what i'm doing wrong. Do i need some brackets or sth like that?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible question. While I don't know offhand what the problem is, there is always the possibility that something *before* this (even not table-related) could be altering the behavior. I'm not recommending you dump your whole latex/markdown report into the question, I suggest you find the smallest reproducible subset of the report that repeats the problem and then [edit] it into your question.

Comment: Try removing the word enter at the front of the first line.

Comment: This is my all code, only the table and title. 

The word enter appeared by mistake when i made the post, it isn't in my code.

Comment: is your output HTML (as suggested in your YAML header) or PDF?

Comment: yes, my output is HTML